Excel vba :how to copy cell data from Current Workbook to another workbook without opening it
I have workbooks: 1) Bill.xlsm     2) Stockbook.xlsm
Now i want to copy cell data (Stock sales/purchase) from "BILL.XLSM"!Sheet1 which is opened currently, to "stockbook.xlsm"!Sheet1 Range C1:C5
I don't want to open "STOCK.." workbook and hang the current workbook.
I just want to copy data.
Is there any method, without opening Workbook in vba, just copy data to that specific worksheet stored in specific workbook(how to refer ? and how to save data ?)
From - BILL.xlsm !Sheet1 Range A1:A5  to  "Stock...xlsm"!Sheet1 Range C1:C5
Thanks for your solution in advance
I Tried to google method to open another workbook in hidden mode, and copy paste the data from Currently opened workbook into another closed workbook... but not found..

What do you mean with *hang the current workbook"? I transfer cell contents from different workbooks by opening the receiving workbook, open the second one, copy the data, and close the second one again. I never came across a malfunction that could be interpreted as "hanging".

Open Bill, open Stockbook and enter =[Bill.xlsm]Sheet1!A1 in [StockBook]Sheet1!C1 and copy down to C5. Save and close StockBook. If that doesn't work for you, share in detail what's wrong with it.

@VBasic2008 - that's going to generate links in Stockbook and any changes in Bill will be reflected in Stockbook each time it is opened. OP said "I just want to copy data"

You can't do this with VBA and you would struggle to do it in any language.
Firstly we need to dispel your mythical "hanging" scenario. Opening a workbook in VBA will not cause the VBA to hang - unless you have written some code that is causing that.
For example - the workbook you are opening may have an Workbook_Open macro that is causing the issue. If so, then you can disable that. See Open a workbook from VBA and disable Workbook_Open() code?
This snippet of code will copy values from the current workbook to another after disabling macros in the other workbook.
Sub demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Dev\BookToOpenWithMacros.xlsm")
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B3").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B3").Value
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    MsgBox "the macro continued to run"
End Sub


Copy Values to Closed Workbook

When developing a code that opens a new (hidden) instance of Excel, then opens a workbook in it and performs some operations...etc., if an error occurs, the workbook and the instance remain open. Therefore when you 'fix' the issue and rerun the code, Excel might hang. The following should resolve most of the problems.

Sub CopyValues()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "A1:A5"
    Const DST_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test"
    Const DST_FILE_NAME As String = "StockBook.xlsm"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "C1"
    Const MSG_SUCCESS As String = "Values copied."
    
    ' Source (Open)
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Destination (Closed)
    
    Dim dFilePath As String:
    dFilePath = DST_FOLDER_PATH & Application.PathSeparator & DST_FILE_NAME
    If Len(Dir(dFilePath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & dFilePath & """ doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dwb = Workbooks(DST_FILE_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not dwb Is Nothing Then ' is possibly open in current application
        If StrComp(dwb.FullName, dFilePath, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' equal
            MsgBox "The file """ & dFilePath & """ is open!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    Dim MsgString As String, Success As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' prevent leaving new Excel and workbook open
    
    Dim dxlApp As Application: Set dxlApp = New Application
    Set dwb = dxlApp.Workbooks.Open(dFilePath)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS) _
        .Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Copy.
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
    ' Flag.
    MsgString = MSG_SUCCESS
    Success = True
    
ProcExit:
    ' Close.
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent infinite loop if error in continuation
        If Not dwb Is Nothing Then dwb.Close SaveChanges:=Success
        If Not dxlApp Is Nothing Then dxlApp.Quit
        MsgBox MsgString, IIf(Success, vbInformation, vbCritical)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgString = "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


This function use the ADODB Connection to reach the closed workbook.
Input parameters

Wbname : The fullpath of the workbook as string
Shname : The name of the sheet to access
row,col : the physical row and column value of the cell the set/get
ValueToWrite : The data to write in
wr : if TRUE write operation. Default False


Function ReadWriteClosedWb(Wbname As String, Shname As String, row As Long, col As Long, Optional ValueToWrite As Variant, Optional wr As Boolean = False) As Variant

If row < 1 Or col < 1 Then ReadWriteClosedWb = CVErr(2015): Exit Function

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Wbname & _
";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

conn.Open connstring
Dim record As ADODB.Recordset
Set record = New ADODB.Recordset
record.Open "select * from [" & Shname & "$]", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
If row = 1 Then
    If wr Then
        ReadWriteClosedWb = CVErr(2015)
    Else
        ReadWriteClosedWb = record.Fields(col).Name
    End If
Else
    If wr Then
        record.Move row - 1, 1
        record.Fields(col) = ValueToWrite
        ReadWriteClosedWb = 0
        record.Update
    Else
        record.Move row - 1, 1
        ReadWriteClosedWb = record.Fields(col)
    End If
End If
record.Close
conn.Close

End Function


Sub testsub()

res = ReadWriteClosedWb("C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\ClosedWb.xlsm", "Sheet1", 2, 2, 123456, True)

End Sub


